# Java runtime error with navigation view

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to run my project but it crashes upon load. I have my proguard here as it has been the source of all issues so far and my error below that.

I have tried:

- reinstalling android studio
- clean build
- rebuild project
- deleting known references to missing classes

Pastebin file has my gradle output as its too long to be put here:
http://pastebin.com/rqU6vpd4

My proguard file is as shown:

```
-dontwarn android.net.http.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn org.apache.httpcomponents.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.**
-dontwarn com.android.build.transform.api.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.io.**
-dontwarn org.apache.lang.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.**
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**
-dontwarn org.joda.**
-dontwarn au.com.bytcode.opencsv.**
-dontwarn java.beans.**
-dontwarn com.google.**
-dontwarn java.lang.invoke.**
-dontwarn com.playerize.**
-dontwarn com.parse.**
-dontwarn org.apache.lang.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.**
-dontwarn com.chartboost.**
-dontwarn dagger.**
-dontwarn com.supersonic.**
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**
-dontwarn android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
```

Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.intellidev.bitrichpro/com.intellidev.bitrichpro.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
11-03 15:28:45.678 6098-6098/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.intellidev.bitrichpro.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    enter code here
```

Comment: please post your proguard file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your proguard file to not warn about the `java.beans` package

```
-dontwarn java.beans.**
-dontwarn com.google.vending.**
-dontwarn com.android.vending.**
```

Comment: i did that but still getting errors. updated the pastebin file @JBirdVegas

Comment: @IntelliDev, Updated my response.  The error had 9 unknown classes now its only two.  See the updated answer

Comment: thanks. fixed all the gradle issues but now im getting another error i wasnt before.

Comment: @IntelliDev Awesome.  Please accept the answer if it fixes this problem.  If you open a new question for the next problem then link to it here and I'll have a look

Comment: thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33508722/java-runtime-exception-when-using-navigation-drawer